# compiling the source into object files using gcc -c *.c

Tags: c, windows, compilation, wildcard, object-files

My OS is Windows 10. I'm using command prompt this time to compile.

according to the book that I am reading, to compile all the source files and make it an object files, (in the current directory) do it by typing this command:

```
gcc -c *.c
```

it says the operating system will replace *.c with all the C filenames

But why am I getting this error?

```
gcc: error: *.c: Invalid argument
gcc: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
```

I'm in the right directory.
And when I compile my source files with their respective names, it's working properly. But the '*.c' is not working.

And the same error in linking the object files using '*.o'

Is that command not for windows OS? If not, what is for windows?

Newbie here.

Comment: Cross network duplicate [here](https://superuser.com/questions/460598/is-there-any-way-to-get-the-windows-cmd-shell-to-expand-wildcard-paths). I suggest you install a unix shell simulator and avoid using the windows command prompt. Cygwin is one such possible simulator.

Comment: Are you sure that you have at least one `.c` file in the current working directory? Otherwise `*.c` won't be expanded, hence `gcc` receives single command-line argument `*.c`.

Comment: @GrzegorzSzpetkowski. Yes sir. I'm in the right directory.

Comment: @StoryTeller.. Tnx sir.. I'll read it.

Answer (score 7):

On Unix systems and environments (like MSYS or Cygwin) , wildcards are expanded by the shell (depends), but **in Windows CMD, wildcards are expanded and interpreted by the program that receives**. This sounds strange, but `cmd.exe` does not support wildcard expansion (as an interpreter), but some of its built-in commands do, like `COPY`.

Use a simple program to verify it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    int i;
    for (i = 1; i < argc; i ++)
        printf("%s\n", argv[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

Sample output on Unix:

```sh
$ ./a.out /*
/bin
/boot
/dev
...
/usr
/var
$ ./a.out /\*
/*
$
```

Sample output on Windows:

```
C:\Windows\system32>a.exe C:\*
C:\*
C:\Windows\system32>
```

If you want to let something else expand the wildcard for your program, use [MinGW](https://sourceforge.net/downloads/mingw) (MSYS) or [Windows Subsystem for Linux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) (Win 10 1607 and later).

Answer (score 0):

In Windows, wildcards are *not* supported, thus the error you see.

In UNIX though, what you used, would be correct:

```
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ nano main.c
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ nano fun.h
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ nano fun.c
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$ gcc -c *.c
Georgioss-MacBook-Pro:~ gsamaras$
```

Comment: Mingw manages it internally. in linux I think it is shell dependant

Comment: You'd better clarify your answer as ***In Windows CMD***. Emulated Unix environments like Cygwin still processes wildcards for CLI programs.